# How to take optional user input using asyncio?

Tags: python-asyncio

I am trying to take input asynchronously using asyncio routine.
As input will be taken only occasionally, asyncio is preferred over threading.
Once the input is entered, the coroutine should call something which affects the main thread execution. Example passing information using queue or return statement.

I am using aioconsole library. Please don't suggest keyboard library as it requires root user permissions.

My skip_stop coroutine is not taking user input as expected. I am not seeing `User Entered` log. Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

I have tried running with apython as well.

```
import aioconsole
import logging
import asyncio
import time
# configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')


async def skip_stop(stop_event=None):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        user_input = await aioconsole.ainput()
        logging.info(f"User Entered `{user_input}`")
        # do something based on input
        return 'Hey Stop please'
    logging.info(f"No User Input found, closing the skip stop thread for this iteration")


async def main():
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        stop_event = asyncio.Event()
        skip_stop_task = asyncio.create_task(skip_stop(stop_event))
        # do something on main thread
        time.sleep(1)
        stop_event.set()
        result = await skip_stop_task
        if result == 'Hey Stop please':
            return
        i += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: terminedia is another project which features an async-input - just pip install it, and use `data = await terminedia.ainput()` where apropriate.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, I had to add `await asyncio.wait_for(aioconsole.ainput(), timeout=0.1)` and necessary conditions in except clause to solve the problem. See my answer.

Comment: I did not downvote, I just commented of another library which offers the async input feature.

Answer (score 1):

I see why your program isn't working, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do so I can't say how to fix it.

You create the skip_stop task here:

```
skip_stop_task = asyncio.create_task(skip_stop(modify_index_queue, stop_event, halt_event, synthesizer))
```

but it will not begin to execute until your main task reaches an await expression.  There is no await expression in the next line.  Then you do:

```
stop_event.set()
```

and then:

```
await skip_stop_task
```

This is the first opportunity that skip_stop has a chance to run.  But now `stop_event` is set, so when the task checks the state of stop_event it will not enter its loop.  It returns without doing anything.

Incidentally, if you want to create a minimum example, just strip out all the code that has nothing to do with the problem at hand.  In this case, you could remove all the code involving the synthesizer.  What remains is basically just the creation of a task and the Event objects.  The problem becomes a lot easier to spot.

Comment: Yes, that was the reason. stop_event was already set when the first time it was called. I need to run speak and user_input together.

Comment: Also, if i try to await before, it gets stuck for user input and I can't run the main thread task.

Comment: i have edited the question and provided my solution, pls suggest if you have any other solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was doing it wrong. I need a blocking task inside main thread to run concurrently with skip_stop_task.

For this, I was required to convert the code inside the main to a Future using the to_thread function.

I have used a queue to modify the behaviour of the main thread.

The modified version of the code looks like this:

Note the `.get_nowait()` call in the queue, very important for optional input.

```
from asyncio import QueueEmpty

import aioconsole
import logging
import asyncio
import time
# configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')


async def skip_stop(message_pass_queue_to_main_thread=None):
    while True:
        user_input = await aioconsole.ainput()
        logging.info(f"User Entered `{user_input}`")
        # do something based on input
        # and passing it to main thread to affect its behavior
        await message_pass_queue_to_main_thread.put(user_input)


def my_main_blocking_task():
    time.sleep(1)


async def main():
    i = 0
    message_pass_queue_to_main_thread = asyncio.Queue()
    skip_stop_task = asyncio.create_task(skip_stop(message_pass_queue_to_main_thread))
    while i < 10:
        # do something on main thread
        blocking_future = asyncio.to_thread(my_main_blocking_task)
        await blocking_future
        try:
            user_input_if_any = message_pass_queue_to_main_thread.get_nowait()
            logging.info(f"Doing something on input got from skip_stop `{user_input_if_any}`")
        except QueueEmpty:
            logging.info("no input at this iteration")
        i += 1
    skip_stop_task.cancel()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```